# Access current view from AppDelegate

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I am attempting to access the current view from my App Delegate. Inside my app delegate there is a timed event that accesses a remote server every 30 seconds. If it finds a need to update the current data I need it to show a progress display "Please Wait" modal popup over the current view.

I want to use the DejalActivityView to display the "Please Wait" window over the currently active view, however it requires the currently active view as an input parameter and I cannot find a way to get at it from the App Delegate.

Self.Window.RootViewController returns Null, there is no current view or UIViewController visible that I can find from the delegate.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of doing this, you need to use a different architecture, like notifications.

In the AppDelegate, where you were going to do this, replace it with this:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"showPleaseWaitAlert" object:nil];
```

Then, implement a method like this in your view controller:

```
-(void)showPleaseWait {
  //Show your dialog here
}
```

Then, in a method like `viewDidLoad`, do this:

```
[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(showPleaseWait) name:@"showPleaseWaitAlert" object:nil]
```

Comment: Aha! Thank you for this, having recently come to iOs development from ASP.Net my understanding is still lacking. I am very grateful for this explanation of the 'general approach'. You, my friend, are awesome. Thank you very much!

Comment: @CraigMoore: Thanks! Always glad to help. iOS development isn't quite like anything else. It takes a little getting used to.